Extract certain word (case-insensitive) followed by numbers from Pandas df
Can you extract a series of letters and numbers from bad freeform data in a dataframe?
I want to create a new column in the data frame with data that contains 'NEX' and a series of numbers after it.
import pandas as pd

#Create a Dataframe
data = {
    'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'PROGRAM': [ 'nbu 123456',
                'NBU-123456',
                'nex999999 b12',
                'NXE999999 123',
                'NBU123456 NEX999999']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I think I'm on the right lines with the below, but I somehow need to combine their functionality:-
print(df['PROGRAM'].str.contains('NEX', na=False))
# does not deal with lower case & contains letters NEX not nessary in that order
print(df['PROGRAM'].str.extract(r'([NEX]+\d+)', expand=False))

The result should only bring back NEX999999 (including converting lowercase to uppercase)
df['NEX'] = df['PROGRAM'].str.blahblahblah


You do not need to pre-filter the rows with NEX, your regex can already do that.
One issue with your regex is [NEX], this allows a single character from the N/E/X set, which is not what you want. [NEX]+ would match N or EEEN.
You should use:
df['out'] = df['PROGRAM'].str.upper().str.extract(r'(NEX\d+)', expand=False)

And if you do not care about lower/uppercase:
import re

df['out2'] = df['PROGRAM'].str.extract(r'(NEX\d+)', expand=False, flags=re.I)

And if you just want the digits:
df['out3'] = df['PROGRAM'].str.extract(r'NEX(\d+)', expand=False, flags=re.I)

Output:
   ID              PROGRAM        out       out2    out3
0   1           nbu 123456        NaN        NaN     NaN
1   2           NBU-123456        NaN        NaN     NaN
2   3        nex999999 b12  NEX999999  nex999999  999999
3   4        NXE999999 123        NaN        NaN     NaN
4   5  NBU123456 NEX999999  NEX999999  NEX999999  999999


Mozway, Where did you define 're' in the last two options, as this is very handy?

df['out2'] = df['PROGRAM'].str.extract(r'(NEX\d+)', expand=False, flags=re.I)
^^
NameError: name 're' is not defined

I solved it as need to 'import re'.

Sorry, forgot the import. Note that you can also use case=False
